# How to create RSASSA-PSS keys using openssl?

Tags: rsa, openssl, rsa-pss

I am trying to understand the `RSASSA-PSS` and process of generating keys with `rsassaPss`. I am using below `openssl` command to generate private key:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm rsa-pss          \
    -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048           \
    -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_md:sha256       \
    -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_mgf1_md:sha256  \
    -pkeyopt rsa_pss_keygen_saltlen:20      \
    -out private_test.pem
```

Then I created a self-signed certificate using

```
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -config openssl.conf -days 365 -outform DER -out testing.der
```

But when I read the certificate with

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -inform DER -in testing.der
```

I see that `Signature Algorithm` is set to `sha256WithRSAEncryption`

```
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
```

What I expected is

```
Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
        Hash Algorithm: sha256
        Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha256
         Salt Length: 0x20
        Trailer Field: 0x01 (default)
```

When I check the OID of above genertaed private key

```
openssl asn1parse -in private_test.pem -inform PEM
```

I get

```
0:d=0  hl=4 l=1214 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE
    9:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
   20:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
   22:d=1  hl=4 l=1192 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:302...
```

How can I preserve the `Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss` while creating certificate? Should I set anything in the openssl config file? Also how can I check the `Trailer Field` in my certificate (this is not shown by the `openssl x509 -text -noout`)?

P.S: openssl version `OpenSSL 3.0.2 15`. And this certificate will also be used to issue leaf certificates.

Comment: This is about usage of `openssl`, so off-topic for this SE. But looking at your (incomplete) commands, nowhere do you specify which key to use to sign the certificate when calling `openssl req`. Thus it will likely generate a new one, rather than use the one you created. Try passing it `-key path/to/private/key`. I'd encourage you to read through `man openssl-req`, lots of good information in there.

Comment: Hi @Morrolan, thanks for the answer. But is it possible to set existing private key file in openssl config? And not pass `-key` in openssl req

Comment: I do not know @Preeti. I'd imagine you can. This sounds like something you'll surely find in the man-pages.

Comment: Note `req -new -x509` uses the same key to be _in_ the cert _and_ to sign it, set by commandline `-key` (or `-newkey ... -keyout`) or config `[req] default_keyfile`. The Trailer field only exists in a PSS signature; since you (unintentionally) used a v1.5 key (not the newly created PSS key) and didn't specify `-sigopt` it created a v1.5 signature in which there is no Trailer field, and it is not possible to display something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi @dave_thompson_085, thanks for the answer. Do you know how can I specify existing private key to use in the opensl config? I could not find any info openssl man (maybe I missed it). I don't want to pass `-key` in `openssl req`. I trierd adding `private_key` in the `[req]` section of openssl config but it didn't  help.

Comment: As I said, and the man page says, it's `default_keyfile` in the `[req]` section of the config file.